# Passing current service object to domain will be a anti pattern for DDD?

Tags: design-patterns, domain-driven-design, anti-patterns

I have service which is getting domain from repository and passing its own instance to the domain for some external dependency. Can it become anti pattern? `RichDomainModel` suggests to pass dependency to domain as required, however I am concerned if this can be called as cyclic dependency and would become anti pattern?

```
class Order
{
  private $currencyVal;

  public function __construct()
  {

  }

  public function processBusinessLogic($arg1, $arg2)
  {
      // do some business logic operation on $arg1, $arg2 & $this->currencyVal
  }

  public function populateExternalValue(OrderService $service)
  {
    $this->currencyVal = $service->getCurrencyValue($this);
  }
}


OrderService 
{
  private $orderRepository;
  private $externalServiceClient;

  public function __construct(OrderRepository $orderRepository, Client $externalServiceClient)
  {
    $this->orderRepository = $orderRepository;
    $this->externalServiceClient = $externalServiceClient;
  }

  public function processDomain(Request $request)
  {
     $order = $this->orderRepository->findById($request->orderId);
     $order->populateExternalValue($this);
     $order->processBusinessLogic($request->arg1, $request->arg2);
     $this->orderRepository->save($order);
  }

  public function getCurrencyValue(Order $order) 
  { 
    return $this->externalServiceClient->getValue($order->currency)
  }
}
```

Alternatively I could use something like this but that would lead to `AnemicDomainModel`

```
$order->setCurrencyValue($this->getCurrencyValue($order));
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

1. This is definitely a cyclic dependency and that is an anti-pattern.
2. If you want to enrich the domain model, the logic surrounding `$currencyVal` should move out of `OrderService` and into `Order`.
3. Since the logic depends on `$externalServiceClient`, that client would move into `Order` as well.
4. Note that [anemic domain model](https://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/AnemicDomainModel.html) is an OOP anti-pattern; but you don't have to do OOP. A rich domain model makes sense if you have a rich domain. For a basic CRUD application with very little logic, it may be over-engineering.

Comment: It's initial phase and I have some level of complexity in Order domain which will increase over a period of time and that's the reason I wanted to have rich domain model.
I am wondering if this is cyclic dependency and anti-pattern how can I get rid of it keeping the domain as rich?